# How to delete all desktop notifications forever on SUSE KDE

Tags: x11, kde, desktop, suse

I can't find the "get the hell away from my desktop" button, on SUSE 42.1 KDE.
I want any version of a desktop notification gone forever.
I have log files, I know how to use them. The desktop notifications are unbearable.

How do I disable SUSE KDA desktop notification forever? So they will never come back?

It does not exist here  ->  [image]

Comment: for now I have disabled notifications via ->  mv /usr/share/knotifications5 /usr/share/knotifications5.old and I haven't been annoyed yet.  There should be a regular disable button somewhere.

Comment: You should write this up as an answer and accept it. It's a good tip!